# How to debug and speed up slow has_one association load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

**TL;DR**

```
@payment.order # takes from 3 to 15 seconds, unacceptable
```

There are 1757k Orders and 640k Payments in a Postgres database.
How to debug why it takes so long to load the association, and how to make it faster?
If database indexing is the issue, how to verify whether it is the case or not; how to rebuild an index?

**Discussion**

I have these two legacy models:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :order
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  # SCHEMA
  # t.references :payment, index: true

  belongs_to :payment
end
```

I know that it would be more correct if Payments belonged to Orders, but that's how the app is and can not be changed.

The history is long and convoluted, the `payment_id` on `orders` table has been dropped, restored and `add_index`-ed, values changed in batch tasks.

After one `payment_id` field drop and restore I noticed that calling a simple association load in console takes very long

```
@payment.order
```

Since accessing this association is crucial to app performance, I overwrote the vanilla Rails association

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has_one :order # too slow!

 def order
    return nil if self.new_record?
    return @order ||= Order.where(payment_id: self.id).limit(1).last # takes just 0.3s  
 end
```

Now the load is even faster than it was before, but, naturally, the getter method does not behave like a true association, specifically, I can not use `Payment.joins(:order)`

How do I restore the association and have it performant?

Comment: just a thought, can you try renaiming the association to like `xorder` not that this gets confused internally with ordering in ActiveRecord. Otherwise i'd check if indexes on your tables could help speed things up